# Picture Storage as URL in SQLite DB in Swift 5

Tags: sql, arrays, swift, local-storage

I have a swift project that uses an array of pictures. The array of pictures is kept in storage in the filmanager.default.urls path. The URLs are then kept in a SQLite database. I am able to add to the array without a problem, however, I run into an issue whenever I try to recall it from memory. I do not know if I am saving it wrong or loading it wrong. I will post the code for how I did that here.

```
func save(images: Array<UIImage>, identifier: String) -> Array<String> {
        var picCounter = 0
        var URLs: Array<String> = []
        for pic in images {
            let id = identifier + "makeSureThisCantAccidentallyBeAnID" + String(picCounter)
            let jpgImageData = pic.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            let documentURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first
            let path = documentURL!.appendingPathComponent(id + ".png")
            do {
                try jpgImageData!.write(to: path)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            picCounter += 1
            URLs.append(path.absoluteString)
        }
        return URLs
    }
```

That is my save function. It should store the URLs and return an array of URLs in string format.
Here is my loading function, it should take an array of URLs and return the array of images.

```
func recover(URLarray: Array<String>, identifier: String) -> Array<UIImage> {
        if URLarray[0] == "fake url" {
            let pic = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "LaunchScreen")
            let fakeArray = [pic]
            return fakeArray
        }
        var picCounter = 0
        var imageArray: Array<UIImage> = []
        for url in URLarray {
            //let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: url)
            guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url) else { return imageArray }
            picCounter += 1
            imageArray.append(image)
        }
        return imageArray
    }
```

The "#imageliteral" is a literal image that is used instead of an array if there is no array to load. This should theoretically recall every image without returning nil. Lastly, I will post my SQLite saving function

```
func saveNote(note: Note) {
        connect()
        
        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(
            database,
            "UPDATE remember SET person = ?, memories = ?, imageurl = ? WHERE rowid = ?",
            -1,
            &statement,
            nil
        ) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, NSString(string: note.person).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, NSString(string: note.memories).utf8String, -1, nil)
            var imageURL: String = ""
            for url in note.imageURLs {
                imageURL.append(url)
                imageURL.append("@")
            }
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, NSString(string: imageURL).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 4, note.id)
            if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Error saving note")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error creating note update statement")
        }
        
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
```

This is how I tried to save it. I had to store a URL array as one string so I decided to do so by making it a string I could split with the character "@" if you think that is the problem then please tell me what character or method I could use to do this, as I have tried changing the character. If anyone helps me this far then I am extremely grateful! Thank you!

Comment: Your topic title is misleading.  You are not saving an image as blob with SQLite.

Comment: @El Tomato Thank you! I'm sorry about that and I changed it.